# .NET Entity Framework: What is the Correct Escape Character to Pass a URL via the SQL Method?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I think this may be a pretty basic question, but I can't word it specifically to generate a helpful answer.

I'm going to pass some data via Entity Framework migration to an existing table with Sql().  The column, Url, takes strings.  What escape character(s) do I need to use to pass the Url Value as a string?

In other words, in the code below, do I need to use any escape characters in conjunction with http://www.someurl.com?

Thank you!

```
Sql("INSERT INTO Videos (Name, Url, VideoGenreId, ArtistId) VALUES ('SomeName', 'http://www.someurl.com', 1, 1)");
```

Comment: Is this about safety or just possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.  The data passed to the database without any escape characters with no errors.

I did not anticipate that :)

Thanks.